# How to set kebab-case for file names for refactor "move to new file" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I set kebab-case for the file names for the refactor method (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>) "move to new file" in VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you cannot. The feature has been requested here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81835

and now is an ongoing open Feature-request but without any updates for a longer while (as of this writing) here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/50685

you may upvote it if you like.